# Facing Response code 401 Response message Unauthorized error when running load test for mobile application

Tags: java, android, mobile, jmeter, load-testing

I am using jmeter to run load test of my script recording for mobile application. When i am running the recorded script then i am getting Response code 401 Response message Unauthorized error when running load test for mobile application

Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2017-09-07 06:52:06 UTC
Load time: 37
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 37
Size in bytes: 468
Sent bytes:969
Headers size in bytes: 293
Body size in bytes: 175
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 401
Response message: Unauthorized

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Thu, 07 Sep 2017 06:52:06 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Vary: Cookie
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.21
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Length: 175
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=95
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: application/json
DataEncoding: null

Comment: Is this a question?

Answer (score 0):

As per [401 Unauthorized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) HTTP Status Code description:

> The HTTP 401 Unauthorized client error status response code indicates that the request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

your request seems to be missing credentials.

Depending on your application authentication implementation you should be able either to add [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) and configure it to match your application expectations or alternatively your test may miss (or have improperly working [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations)), for instance it might be a dynamic request parameter, a [HTTP Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) or [HTTP Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies). In the latter case record your test once more, compare generated .jmx scripts, detect differences and work them around using [JMeter's Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors).

Answer (score 0):

Adding HTTP Authorization Manager to Thread Group having username, password and domain (if applicable) to tests works